# Where I can find the system out prints in RCP Product?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a `RCP` application, inside which I have added some `System.out.println()` statements. Now, that I have exported the project as a product, can anyone please tell me where to look for these `System.out.println()` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using the logger framework, the output is not printed into the default `workspace/.metadata/.log` file.

You can start your product with a console though, adding the following parameters to the `ProductName.ini` (e.g. Eclipse.ini) file in your installation directory:
-console
-consoleLog

The ini file should look something like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-console
-consoleLog
```

The output will be printed in the console window.

EDIT
If you get an error message after starting the application: 
`could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console`

You need to add the following bundles to your `ProductName.product` file ('Contents' tab) and export a new product:
org.eclipse.equinox.console
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
org.apache.felix.gogo.command
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now a console window is opening, but, there is some exception. could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console.

Comment: add the "org.eclipse.equinox.console" plugin to your product configuration. You will also need the dependent "org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime" plugin.

Comment: No in your `.product` file, you will have to create a new product. And I forgot you also need the following two bundles: "org.apache.felix.gogo.command" and "org.apache.felix.gogo.shell"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Probably my question is silly. But, I am not able to find the .product in the exported RCP application, can you please help me? :(

Comment: I am sorry.. I am bit confused. can you please explain a little mroe?

Comment: Great! Just for the record, the .product file is in your development environment. From where you generate the actual RCP product. So it is not in your exported RCP application but somewhere in the IDE in a plugin/feature project.